# Overriding operator void * for return status

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

The standard `ios` class overrides the void * operator such that it can be used in conditionals.

```
if (std::cin) { ... }
```

I have a class whose function returns a status.

```
Status DoSomething()
```

It would be good to be able to use `Status` in an if-statement if the use doesn't need a fine-grained return status.

```
if (DoSomething()) { ... }  // just want to know if pass or fail

// or if I need more info
Status s = DoSomething()
switch (s) { ... }
```

Is the `ios` trick good for this use case or not? Is it even a good idiom in general?

Comment: What is Status? A Enum, Class or just #define int?

Comment: It could be anything that makes it the safest (and preferably the easiest) to implement what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it even a good idiom in general?

No. In C++03 you should instead use [safe-bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html). In C++11, you should use `explicit operator bool`. Never use `operator void*` to do bool conversion. They have to be defined on `Status` type, obviously.

Note that this doesn't affect `switch` — to be able to use that, you need to have a conversion operator to an integer or an enumeration.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the link. And I really like the name Cat Plus Plus. :)

Comment: If a conversion to enum or integer exists, it has higher priority when converting to bool than `operator void*`

Answer (score 0):

If you only has one error status, an `enum` is OK. Just assign 0 to that only error status.

Otherwise you need a `class`. But a `class` cannot be used in `switch`, you need a conversion operator to integer type (bool, int, chat, enum etc). Once you have such conversion operator defined, they have higher priority than "void*" when the context requires a bool value. If you define both `int` and `bool` operator, they will lead to bool conversion ambiguous. So you cannot use an object in both `if` and `switch`, except the only error status is converted to 0.

However, you can use the safe-bool idiom (do not use operator bool, which can be used in switch accidentally), and add a function to return enum, or integer for switch.

```c++
class Status {
public:
    enum Code {
        RUNNING = 1,
        IDDLE = 2,
        ERROR = -1,
        STOPPED = -2
    };

    explicit Status(Code code) : code_(code) {}

    bool ok() const { return code_ > 0; }

    operator void*() const
    { return ok() ? const_cast<Status*>(this) : 0; }

    bool operator!() const
    { return !ok(); }

    Code code() const { return code_; }

private:
    Code code_;
};

Status s(Status::STOPPED);

if (s) { .... }
switch (s.code()) { .... }
```